# Golang Generics exclude slice or array types

Tags: go, generics

I have a function with a generic in Go that should not be applied to either slices or arrays. But I don't have an idea how to do this. I found examples for that, but only for Typescript which doesn't bring me further. So as an example, I'd like to have sth. like:

`func sth[T anything_but_slices_or_arrays](arg T) { ...doSth... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get halfway there with the `comparable` constraint, as slices do not implement this interface:

```golang
func foo[T comparable](arg T) {
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", arg) // for example
}


func main() {
    i := []int{42}
    foo(i) // <- compiler error: []int does not satisfy comparable
}
```

However, **arrays** (of comparable types) are:

```golang
func foo[T comparable](arg T) {
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", arg) // for example
}


func main() {
    i := [1]int{42}
    foo(i)
```

will compile and run to produce the output:

```
[1]int{42}
```

So it perhaps comes down to how important it is to exclude slices and arrays in your function, and that will come down to what your generic function does.

It is perhaps more common to constrain a generic function only to the extent that is needed to ensure the function can perform the operations it wishes.  i.e. if the function needs to be able to compare args of a generic type, then a `comparable` constraint makes sense, but if a function doesn't need any specific capabilities, then let it accept `any`.

If you simply don't *want* the function used with values of some type (or types) arbitrarily, even though there is nothing wrong with doing so in terms of what the function does, then this might be better policed and regulated by other means (code review, pull requests etc.).

It's hard to say for sure without knowing exactly what your generic function is going to do. :)

Comment: Thank you - This is actually what I need. Or it's good enough, respectively. I have two functions for querying a database. One should return only one entity, the other one a slice. That's what I need it for.

EDIT: I just saw that my problem is actually not solvable. I can't type a function type so it's not applicable for me at all :-(

Comment: @marczahn, querying a database is accessing data which is not know until runtime, so trying to impose generics on the problem doesn’t save you from runtime errors. This is why scanning/decoding functions still need to return errors.

Comment: @JimB - Of course. But this would happen anyway. Right now, my function gets a pointer to a variable of the expected type. Instead I would like to get the result as a return value which then requires the type on call-time.

Comment: @marczahn worth pointing out here is that any generic type param that is used only in the return value means that GoLang is not be able to infer the generic type in use.  i.e. you will need to be explicit when instantiating and invoking your generic function e.g.: `i, err := GetValueFromDB[int]()` [yuck] :)

I still think you are using the wrong tool for the job.  The func doesn't care if a pointer to a slice/array is passed to receive a value; it will likely fail with an error, as it should.  Not everything can be caught at compile-time (and the effort of trying isn't always worthwhile).